# Understanding 1D FFT on 3D data using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft

Could someone kindly explain what the following `MATLAB` line do?

```
fft( data3D, N, dim );
```

`data3D` is an array of size `(NY, NX, NZ)`. `MATLAB` documentation says

> `fft(X,[],DIM)` or `fft(X,N,DIM)` applies the `fft` operation across the dimension `DIM`.

What exactly `fft` calculates across a dimension when the input is a `3D` array?

Comment: It computes a 1D FFT on each 1D "pencil".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @Oliver Charlesworth, the command `fft(X,[],DIM)` should do this:

```
fft_values=zeros(size(X));  %pre-allocate the output array
if (DIM==1)
    for I=1:size(X,2)
        for J=1:size(X,3)
            fft_values(:,I,J) = fft(squeeze(X(:,I,J));
        end
    end
elseif (DIM==2)
    for I=1:size(X,1)
        for J=1:size(X,3)
            fft_values(I,:,J) = fft(squeeze(X(I,:,J));
        end
    end
elseif (DIM==3)
    for I=1:size(X,1)
        for J=1:size(X,2)
            fft_values(I,J,:) = fft(squeeze(X(I,J,:));
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You have nicely put it into code. Would you mind shortly describe it mathematically as well? I would be absolutely helpful to fully understand the concept.

Comment: @A2009: There isn't much more to describe.  What is still unclear from the above answer?